# Ibatis binding exception error message

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to implement the following ibatis insert annotation but keep getting the following error message:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'person' not
>   found. Available parameters are [arg1, arg0, param1, param2]

This is my code so far. How do I fix it?

```
@(Insert("INSERT INTO profile (person, school) VALUES (#{person}, #{school})";)
void insertOne(TestTextMessage person, String school)
```

Some context:

Tried this... `@(Insert("INSERT INTO profile (person, school) VALUES (#{arg0}, #{arg1})";)` but getting a java.lang.Assertion error right now. TestTextMessage is a class containing the following values:

```
@Data
@NoArgs
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestTextMessage {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age;
}
```

and currently I call it like this:

```
messageMapper.insertOne(new TestTextMessage(person1), SchoolType.EDENGLEN);
```

if i move school type to the class, then it should work but then how do i assign a value to school type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `arg0` and `arg1`

```
@(Insert("INSERT INTO profile (person, school) VALUES (#{arg0}, #{arg1})")
```

or

Use `@Param` to give param a name.

```
void insertOne(@Param("person")TestTextMessage person, @Param("school") String school)
```

Comment: The second option still doesnot works. @Dean

But the first option works